# Out of Memory although increasing momery limit

Tags: php, memory

When i execute some script with php language for a big data, like Export data, Extraction and Print data, an error has been occurred:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 493617152) (tried to allocate 345571051 bytes)
```

Although I have increased the memory in the script by the instruction below:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '3072M');
```

And for more assurance, I have even modified the value of memory_limit in php.ini file to 3072M:

```
memory_limit=3072M
```

The size of RAM on the server used is 4GB.

What's the problem there?

Comment: If the operation you are trying is so big, you would be better off by breaking it down. Think Gearman. Or, you can break it into small pieces by using cron for different operations.

Comment: Did you restart the web server after changing the ini file?

Comment: yes, i did, and it's reset yesterday, and i recheck today!

Answer (score 0):

`ini_set('memory_limit', '3072M');` is simply ignored: No scritp can increase its own memory limit - would be a nice attack vector for any shared webhost!

**Edit**

If you run it from the command line, try php -d memory_limit=3072M /path/to/file

If you run it from a webserver edit php.ini, -htaccess or whatever is needed for your installation

Comment: -1 - Name: memory_limit Default: "128M" Changeable: PHP_INI_ALL - Memory limit can be changed dynamically; though it may well be disabled by hosting companies

Comment: i have edit the php.ini file and i set the new value, also i set the value from the script but the same error appears with a big data!